# How to pass cypress parent variables through childs and returns them back

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

i'm currently creating a few variables at the main file of my cypress automation.

parent file: cypress/test*automation/*`parent_file.spec.cy.js`

```
var access_token;
let _id;
let QRCode;
let access_token_QR;
let uuid;
let self;
let payment;
```

I created another file that contains the actual automation which basically needs those variables to be executed inside of it.

child file: cypress/test*automation/*`child_file.spec.cy.js`

There's a secondary child_file that use those variables too which leads into a problem because if i declare the variables at the parent file they won't be readed at the child file. and it returns this error:

[image]

Is there a way i can declare the variables at the parent file and use them inside the child files with this flow:

> `parent`
> `var` variableA = 10
>
> `child_1`
> use the variableA and change its value to 20.
>
> `child_2`*
> Get the variableA from child*1 which now is 20 and print that value in child_2

I made something like this already to test it out but i couldn't retrieve the variableA from the parent inside the child.

Main parent file: `cypress/automation/parent_file.spec.cy.js`

```
import { test1 } from "./test1";
import { test2 } from "./test2";

describe("Test suite", () => {
  var variableA = 10;
  child_one();
  child_two();
});
```

Child file: `cypress/automation/modules/child_one.spec.cy.js`

```
export function child_one{
  it("Can do something", () => {
    variableA = 20;
  });
}
```

Child file: `cypress/automation/modules/child_two.spec.cy.js`

```
export function child_one{
  it("Can do something", () => {
    cy.log("variableA", variableA)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [Variables and Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases)

```js
// child 1

export function child1 {
  it('a test in child 1', () => {
    cy.wrap(20).as('variableA')
  });
}
```

```js
// child 2

export function child2 {
  it('a test in child 2', () => {
    cy.get('@variableA').then(variableA => { cy.log(variableA) })
  });
}
```

Make sure you don't run the child tests independently, as you have introduced tight coupling (generally a bad thing).

Comment: Thanks for the response! i will follow your words and avoid coupling.